# Plug-in architecture, design dilemma

Tags: wpf, inheritance, architecture, dependencies

Here is my problem,

I have a couple of audio plug-ins, they all inherit from a *Filter* base class. Now I am looking forward to create a UI for them so that users can select/configure them.

The thing I am stuck on is about implementing the plugin properties.

When I make them as *FilterParameter* type, against (double or float type), it is much much easier for me to create their UI through a unique DataTemplate than creating a DataTemplate for each plugin type.

The *FilterParameter* class is a type I created which contains *Description, Min, Max, Value* members; it's a real time saver, but while refactoring my design (with VS dependency graph), I just found out that it creates a lot of dependencies for the plugin types. While I am satisified with the inheritance hierarchy now, these relationships Plugin <-> FilterParameter do dirty my graph again.

What would you do in that case ?

Go the hard path, keep simple types for properties and provide a dedicated DataTemplate for each type ?

Or keep going in a generic mood, accounting the advantages/disadvantages versus the above method ?

Thank you !!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If being generic got the job done, and there were other design constraints or drivers that supported this approach then I'd probably stick with that.

But if keeping things generic, or within a narrow / tightly defined band starts to limit what I can do functionally, or starts distorting other aspects of the system then it's definitely time to go the hard path.  Small pain now, less (larger) pain later.

Comment: That's what I did, I just removed these extra types, now my graph stays clean; in the end it simpler/cleaner even though there is more work for UI but at least there won't be dependencies there, too ... :-)